# How did Lance hurt his leg?

Tags: the-new-heroes

In Michael Carrol's series (*Superhuman Clash*, [*Quantum Prophecy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Heroes)) there is a character named Lance McKendrick, an ex-con who is also very smart. He's part of a team with the other main characters in *Superhuman*, *The Ascension*, & parts of *Stronger*, before leaving and striking it out on his own and having adventures (which are chronicled in *Hunter*). Lance eventually meets up with some of his former team mates and the main characters of the *Quantum* series in the book *Crossfire*, but now has a cane and limps. How did he get this injury?

Comment: I couldn't find any tags for the books or the series, and don't have enough points to make a new tag. Maybe someone can make a new tag for me? Thanks :)

Comment: Is this tag appropriate?

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure he loses in a minefield in one of the books (maybe *Hunter*; I forget) — stepped on a bomb. I'm not sure though. It's been a while since I've read them! But I definitely remember him making a bomb or minefield joke in *The Chasm* regarding his missing leg.